# Why am I getting the "can't modify frozen String" error when I am not modifying the hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the `can't modify frozen String` error on the `User.create(name:name,email:email)`. But I am not modifying the hash at all. All I am doing is creating a new `User` object with the hash `name` and `email`. I am not modifying them. Can someone please clarify as to why I am getting this? Thank you!

Code:

```
users = {'John' => 'john@john.com', 'Sara' => 'sara@sara.com'}
def create_users_from_hash(users)
  users.each do |name, email|
    User.create(name:name,email:email)
  end
end
```

Comment: Could it be an issue in the `User.create` method?

Comment: What does `User.create` do? Is this `rails`? If so, you might want to tag the question as such to get rails developers to look at it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use create! to find where is wrong.Sometimes error will be raised when you want to access an inaccessiable field.